# How to form the Kendo UI TreeView with local Data

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have following JSON data:

```
{
  "Id": "Network_01",
  "name": "Network",
  "nodes": {
    "siteName": {
      "name": "sites",
      .....
    }
  },
  "links":{
    "linksName": {
      "name": "sites",
      .....
    }
  },
  "demands":{
    "demandsName": {
      "name": "sites",
      .....
    }
  }
}
```

I have this format, I get from server and assigned to one variable like "datas"

In Kendo UI Treeview,

```
var treeview = $("#tree").data("kendoTreeView");
var viewModel = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    data: datas,
    schema: {
        model: {
            children: ["nodes", "siteName"]
        }
    }
});

var treeview = $("#tree").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: kendo.observableHierarchy(viewModel),
    dataTextField: ["name"]
}).data("kendoTreeView");
```

Here i am getting First Name (Network). But i can't get children nodes.

I want network has three childs

network -> sites, links, demands

asn Sites has one child is siteName.

How to format this treeview in kendo UI

Comment: Could you please provide your JSON data and treeview structure sample/screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You JSON data is not formatted correctly.  It has a few problems

1. There were no [] indicating that that elements were in an array.
2. The structure of the data in your nodes section did not have a consistent naming convention for all the elements in the nodes section.

   I've included a code snippet that that shows a working example.

If you go to http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/local-data-binding, you will see how to do a multilevel tree.

```js
 var viewModel = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
   data: [{
     "Id": "Network_01",
     "name": "Network",
     "nodes": [{
       "name": "siteName"
     }, {
       "name": "linksName"
     }, {
       "name": "demandsName"
     }]
   }],
   schema: {
     model: {
       children: "nodes"
     }
   }
 });

 $("#tree").kendoTreeView({
   dataSource: viewModel,
   dataTextField: "name"
 });
```

```css
         #example {
           text-align: center;
         }
         .demo-section {
           display: inline-block;
           vertical-align: top;
           width: 220px;
           text-align: left;
           margin: 0 2em;
         }
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />

<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>


<div class="demo-section k-header">
  <h4>Inline data (default settings)</h4>
  <div id="tree"></div>
</div>
```